# phpMyAdmin + CentOS 6.0 - Forbidden

Tags: phpmyadmin, centos, selinux

I always get this message when I would like access my phpMyAdmin.

```
w3m localhost/phpmyadmin

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server.

Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at localhost Port 80
```

Install steps:

```
rpm --import http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/packages/RPM-GPG-KEY.dag.txt
yum install http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.2- 2.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm
yum install phpmyadmin
```

Add Aliases

```
vi /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
Alias /mysqladmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

Change from cookie to http

```
vi /usr/share/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
[...]
 /* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';
[...]
```

Restart

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

SELinux - /etc/httpd

```
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_config_t:s0 .
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0       ..
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_config_t:s0 conf
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_config_t:s0 conf.d
lrwxrwxrwx. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_log_t:s0 logs -> ../../var/log/httpd
lrwxrwxrwx. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_modules_t:s0 modules -> ../../usr/lib64/httpd/modules
lrwxrwxrwx. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_config_t:s0 run -> ../../var/run/httpd
```

SELinux - /usr/share/phpmyadmin

```
drwxr-xr-x. root root   system_u:object_r:usr_t:s0       .
drwxr-xr-x. root root   system_u:object_r:usr_t:s0       ..
-rw-r--r--. root root   system_u:object_r:usr_t:s0       browse_foreigners.php
-rw-r--r--. root root   system_u:object_r:usr_t:s0       calendar.php
-rw-r--r--. root root   system_u:object_r:usr_t:s0       changelog.php
-rw-r--r--. root root   system_u:object_r:usr_t:s0       chk_rel.phph
.
.
.
-rw-r--r--. root root   system_u:object_r:usr_t:s0       view_create.php
```

OS

```
centos-release-6-0.el6.centos.5.x86_64
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Edit your httpd.conf file as follows:

```
# nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Add the following lines here:

```
<Directory "/usr/share/phpmyadmin">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Issue the following command:

```
# service httpd restart
```

If your problem is not solved then disable your SELinux.

Comment: is it possible to allow from an interface like eth0 instead of all, i'm using virtualbox with nat

Comment: This suggestion helped solve my problem. <Directory "usr/share/phpmyadmin">                                                    Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. Then I changed the filename config.sample.inc.php to config.inc.php and also, edited the file so that $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = my ip address of host server (instead of localhost) and it finally worked. (I have no clue what I'm doing, but can someone confirm if what I did was correct for someone else who might find themselves in my position?)

Comment: also you can add this for specific vhost, others will have permission denied (for example for admin only)

Comment: This actually worked for me, as my host set up a machine with CentOS 6.8 instead of 7. I just had to switch the code for 7 (see Hyder's answer) to this, and it works well.

Answer (score 31):

None of the configuration above worked for me on my CentOS 7 server. After hours of searching, that's what worked for me:

Edit file phpMyAdmin.conf

`sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf`

And replace this at the top:

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       #Require ip 127.0.0.1
       #Require ip ::1
       Require all granted
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Comment: This should be the answer. Worked perfectly

Comment: Additionally had to do  "yum install php"

Comment: This just saved me from a quickly worsening headache- thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked for me. I had been trying to fix this for last 2 days. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: Worked perfectly

Answer (score 8):

I tried all answers provided here: editing phpMyAdmin.conf, changing selinux context for phpmyadmin folder, disabling selinux... but I still got a 'Forbidden' from the web server.

I finally found what I was missing in Edouard Thiel post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23235363/forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-phpmyadmin-on-this-server) :

`$ yum install php`

then restart httpd :

`$ service httpd restart`  => for centos 6 hots

`$ systemctl restart httpd` => for centos 7 hosts

What has me amazed is why php is not installed as dependency for phpmyadmin in the first place.

Regards,
Fred

Comment: this is exactly what helped me and exactly what bothers me - why php is not a dependency for a package, that requires it even by it's name...

Comment: This worked for me. I thought I installed php previously but anyway it should have given a different error other than 403

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue for two days now. Disabled SELinux and everything but nothing helped. And I realize it just may not be smart to disable security for a small fix. Then I came upon this article - http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux/ that explains how SELinux operates. So this is what I did and it fixed my problem.

1. Enable access to your main phpmyadmin directory by going to parent directory of phpmyadmin (mine was html) and typing:

   ```
   chcon -v --type=httpd_sys_content_t phpmyadmin
   ```
2. Now do the same for the index.php by typing:

   ```
   chcon -v --type=httpd_sys_content_t phpmyadmin/index.php
   ```

   Now go back and check if you are getting a blank page. If you are, then you are on the right track. If not, go back and check your httpd.config directory settings. Once you do get the blank page with no warnings, proceed.
3. Now recurse through all the files in your phpmyadmin directory by running:

   ```
   chron -Rv --type=httpd_sys_content_t phpmyadmin/*
   ```

Go back to your phpmyadmin page and see if you are seeing what you need. 
If you are running a web server that's accessible from outside your network, make sure that you reset your SELinux to the proper security level. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Non of the above mentioned solutions worked for me. Below is what finally worked:

```
#yum update
#yum install phpmyadmin
```

Be advised, phpmyadmin was working a few hours earlier. I don't know what happened.

After this, going to the browser, I got an error that said `./config.inic.php can't be accessed`

```
#cd /usr/share/phpmyadmin/
#stat -c %a config.inic.php
#640
#chmod 644 config.inic.php
```

This shows that the file permissions were 640, then I changed them to 644. 
Finially, it worked.

Remember to restart httpd.

```
#service httpd restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem when I tape the URL

```
https://www.nameDomain.com/phpmyadmin
```

the forbidden message shows up, because of the rules on /use/share/phpMyAdmin directory 
I fix it by adding in this file `/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf` in this section

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
    ....
</Directory>
```

these line of rules

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   Order Deny,Allow
   Deny from All
   Allow from 127.0.0.1
   Allow from ::1
   Allow from All
   ...
</Directory>
```

you save the file, then you restart the apache service whatever method you choose `service httpd graceful` or `service httpd restart` it depends on your policy

for security reasons you can specify one connection by setting one IP address if  your IP does not change, else if your IP changes every time you have to change it also.

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   Order Deny,Allow
   Deny from All
   Allow from 127.0.0.1
   Allow from ::1
   Allow from 105.105.105.254 ## set here your IP address
   ...
</Directory>
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue.

Only after I changed in php.ini variable

display_errors = Off

to

display_errors = On

Phpadmin started working.. crazy....

Comment: That conf has nothing to do with phpmyadmin. This happened probably because you previously edited the right conf but forgot to restart httpd. Then after changing errors you restarted and the previous edit was also applied.