# Forbidden :You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin on this server

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Hi I have installed phpmyadmin on my centos machine and when I try to hit `phpmyadmin` through my browser I get this error :

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access `phpmyadmin` on this server.
```

My `phpmyadmin.conf` file has following content:

```
# phpMyAdmin - Web based MySQL browser written in php
# 
# Allows only localhost by default
#
# But allowing phpMyAdmin to anyone other than localhost should be considered
# dangerous unless properly secured by SSL

Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin


<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/>
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

# These directories do not require access over HTTP - taken from the original
# phpMyAdmin upstream tarball
#
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/lib/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/frames/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

# This configuration prevents mod_security at phpMyAdmin directories from
# filtering SQL etc.  This may break your mod_security implementation.
#
#<IfModule mod_security.c>
#    <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
#        SecRuleInheritance Off
#    </Directory>
#</IfModule>
```

Kindly help me resolve this issue. Any lead is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: But I am talking about Lamp not wamp FYI

Comment: You are currently only allowing localhost to access in `usr/share/phpmyadmin`  I would recommend only adding a whitelist of IPs for security.

Comment: possible duplicate of [phpMyAdmin + CentOS 6.0 - Forbidden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499849/phpmyadmin-centos-6-0-forbidden)

Comment: You mean to say replacing 127.0.0.1 with my machines IP. I have done that too but this error persists.

Comment: That ans is not working for me. any help !!

Comment: Have you added that in your `httpd.conf` file ? Have you restarted your apache server ?

Comment: I have replaced all the occurrences of 127.0.0.1 with my IP . No I have not added that to httpd.conf file. How to do that. can you describe me the steps to resolve this issue.

Comment: Check how to configure httpd.conf in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7552989/696364).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to follow the following steps:

Find line that read follows

```
Require ip 127.0.0.1
```

Replace with your workstation IP address:

```
Require ip 10.1.3.53
```

Again find the following line:

```
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Replace as follows:

```
Allow from 10.1.3.53
```

Also find `deny from all` and comment it in the entire file.

Save and close the file.`Restart Apache httpd server`:

```
# service httpd restart
```

Edit: Since this is the selected answer and gets best visibility ... please also **make sure that PHP is installed**, otherwise you get same `Forbidden` error.

Comment: I do that and work fine, but I need to allow to more than 1 IP addr, how can I do that? or better, how can I allow to public access?

Comment: You can specify an IP range like this: `Require ip 192.168` Do not include `Allow from` inside `<RequireAny>` block. Documentation here: [link](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_authz_core.html)

Comment: This is the correct answer. And if anyone is wondering, the file is located here - /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf

Comment: Thank you for posting the actual secure answer!

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved my life <3

Comment: Since yours is the selected answer, could you add at the end that `PHP` should also be installed ? Otherwise you get same `Forbidden` error, which is not intuitive.

Comment: How did that other answer get 99 votes, just shows how many people needed this but knew nothing and it worked for them but they don't care about security

Answer (score 121):

None of the configuration above worked for me on my CentOS 7 server. After hours of searching, that what worked for me:

Edit file phpMyAdmin.conf

`sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf`

And replace the existing `<Directory> ... </Directory>` node with the following:

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       #Require ip 127.0.0.1
       #Require ip ::1
       Require all granted
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Comment: for Cent OS 7 it's perfect

Comment: What (important) changes are there in these new lines?

Comment: This is NOT the right answer! You don't want to `Require all granted` since that will allow any host to access phpMyAdmin. The intent of `Require ip 127.0.0.1` is to only allow the localhost access, which is secure.

Comment: I know the thinking is that this is insecure, and I can understand as well, but what's the correct practice in this case? Many people use dynamic IPs which don't stick. I would change the configuration to this temporarily and then change it back so it is only open when necessary, but it doesn't seem like an optimal solution.

Comment: The answer is not even clear. Replace this at the top...What are we to replace?

Comment: it's perfect (for me) because yes for my case (a hosting company serving thousands of clients) I will allow any host to access phpMyadmin with a valid password.

Comment: Hi.  Given the security implications of this answer, I think it would be better if you explain what changes this replacement makes in practice, and what effect those changes have.

Answer (score 61):

On a fresh install on CENTOS7 I have tried the above methods (edit phpMyAdmin.conf and add Require all granted), it still does'nt work. Here is the solution : install the `mod_php` module :

```
$ sudo yum install php
```

then restart httpd :

```
$ sudo systemctl restart httpd
```

and voila !

Comment: This installation is so much better handled in Ubuntu IMO... but hey, thats life.

Comment: Correct answer for me. Nor php or httpd were installed on my machine. Installed phpmyadmin, then httpd and at the end php, and now it's working!

Comment: Nice direction. One must first ensure that php is installed.

Comment: Kind of ridiculous that php is not included as a dependency for phpMyAdmin

Comment: I installed mod_php: `yum -y install mod_php` and restart apache. It worked.

Comment: This worked for me i was using `Centos 7`

Answer (score 8):

To allow from all:

```
#Require ip 127.0.0.1
#Require ip ::1
Require all granted
```

Comment: @DaemonOfTheWest, what does this do?

Comment: @gwg - if anyone figures out a valid user/password combination, they can access your DB - which will really suck - even more so if you forgot to run /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation

Comment: Actually, do this if your setup requires it. Like installing phpmyadmin for multiple users who need to access it via internet or your intranet... And secure your installation via other means. Its appalling to see people telling 'never do this'. They dont seem to know what phpmyadmin was developed for.

Answer (score 5):

Edit file: `sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf` and replace yours with following:

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Restart Apache: `service httpd restart`

(phpMyAdmin v4.0.10.8)

Comment: tried your solution got : Not Found

The requested URL /phpMyAdmin was not found on this server.

Comment: Then added : Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin.....now getting : Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /phpMyAdmin on this server.

Comment: Sorry it didnt work for you. It is a 2.5year old answer. But to try and debug, make sure `/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/` exist or change the path in your config.

Comment: ls -lthr /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/
total 924K
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1.2K Mar 29  2017 webapp.php
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3.5K Mar 29  2017 view_operations.php
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 7.0K Mar 29  2017 view_create.php

Answer (score 4):

First edit the file /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf and add the additional line to the directory settings:

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
allow from 192.168.1.0/15
</Directory>
```

If you wanted to allow access to everybody then you could just change it to:

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
```

Allow in all sections of the file.

A restart (service httpd restart) is enough to pick this up.

I found this after 2 days rigorous research, (find it [here](http://squeezesetup.wordpress.com/allowing-network-access-to-phpmyadmin/)) and worked just right for me.

Comment: I try to do that and dont work, dont allow to all access phpmyadmin, stil have forbidden page

Comment: "allow from" should be changed to "Required ip" in both 2 lines, delete 2 lines of order and deny, then it would work.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the answer with the most votes is it doesn't explain the reasoning for the solution.

For the lines `Require ip 127.0.0.1`, you should instead add the ip address of the host that plans to access phpMyAdmin from a browser. For example `Require ip 192.168.0.100`. The `Require ip 127.0.0.1` allows localhost access to phpMyAdmin.

Restart apache (httpd) after making changes. I would suggest testing on localhost, or using command line tools like curl to very a http GET works, and there is no other configuration issue.

Answer (score 2):

Centos 7 php install comes with the ModSecurity package installed and enabled which prevents web access to phpMyAdmin. At the end of phpMyAdmin.conf, you should find

```
# This configuration prevents mod_security at phpMyAdmin directories from
# filtering SQL etc.  This may break your mod_security implementation.
#
#<IfModule mod_security.c>
#    <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
#        SecRuleInheritance Off
#    </Directory>
#</IfModule>
```

which gives you the answer to the problem. By adding

```
    SecRuleEngine Off
```

in the block "Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/", you can solve the 'denied access' to phpmyadmin, but you may create security issues.

Answer (score 2):

[Find your IP address](https://whatismyipaddress.com/) 
and replace where ever you see 127.0.0.1 with your workstation IP address you get from the link above.

```
. . .
Require ip your_workstation_IP_address
. . .
Allow from your_workstation_IP_address
. . .
Require ip your_workstation_IP_address
. . .
Allow from your_workstation_IP_address
. . .
```

and in the end don't forget to restart the server

```
sudo systemctl restart httpd.service
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply go to phpmyadmin.conf file and change "deny from all" to "allow from all".
Well it worked for me, hope it works for you as well.

Answer (score 1):

With the latest version of phpmyadmin 5.0.2+ at least

Check that the actual installation was completed correctly,

Mine had been copied over into a sub folder on a linux machine rather that being at the

```
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/
```

Comment: Problem with me was the phpmyadmin was uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

In appserver I got same problem and I went to 'C:\AppServ\Apache24\conf\extra' folder I modify httpd-vhosts.conf file from

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"
#ServerName www.example.com:80
</VirtualHost>
```

to

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
DocumentRoot "C:\AppServ\www"
#ServerName www.example.com:80
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
For Centos OS (7.x), installed phpMyadmin -> "sudo yum install phpmyadmin"

Edit file: "sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf"

Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip [...your_device_ip...]
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from [...your_device_ip...]
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

Change line:
Require ip 118.2.141...
Allow from 118.2.141...

And restart the server:
"Sudo service httpd restart"

Database interface access link: http://your_device_ip/phpmyadmin/
Good luck!
```