# PhpMyAdmin error: 403 forbidden

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

I had phpmyadmin installed but when i was on the site : ip/phpmyadmin i tried to logon, but i couldent, it would not redirect me so I removed it and reinstalled.

From then on I cant even connected to the site. In the /etc/httpd/phpMyAdmin.conf file I have added my ips four times like so...

```
# phpMyAdmin - Web based MySQL browser written in php
# 
# Allows only localhost by default
#
# But allowing phpMyAdmin to anyone other than localhost should be considered
# dangerous unless properly secured by SSL

Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/>
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
      Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
    </IfModule>
</Directory>

# These directories do not require access over HTTP - taken from the original
# phpMyAdmin upstream tarball
#
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/lib/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/frames/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

# This configuration prevents mod_security at phpMyAdmin directories from
# filtering SQL etc.  This may break your mod_security implementation.
#
#<IfModule mod_security.c>
#    <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
#        SecRuleInheritance Off
#    </Directory>
#</IfModule>
```

When I restart apache, # service httpd restart, and then go onto the site it still says

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /phpMyAdmin/ on this server.

Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at 6gem.pw Port 80

I cant find any fixes, please help.

Comment: I have not included my IP into this as of now on the site because of purposes. But in the actual file I have added my IP. I run it all of my vps so i added my computer IP

Comment: At first I would check the permissions on the '/usr/share/phpMyAdmin' folder.

Comment: What does the webserver error log say about your rejected connection attempts?

Comment: There are tons of solutions here on stack, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23235363/forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-phpmyadmin-on-this-server

Answer (score 2):

On my server it was security2_module blocking requests after a sql query was posted.

Setting **SecRuleEngine Off** for the phpmyadmin folder did the trick for me:

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
    ...

    <IfModule security2_module>
        SecRuleEngine Off
    </IfModule>
    ...
</Directory>
```

Comment: I've tried so many different attempts of allowing permission, editing htaccess, reinstalling, checking other articles. This is the first time I've seen this mentioned and the only thing that has worked for me.

Comment: For those of us who aren't Apache pros, specifying what file this is in would have made the difference between this answer being useful and being useless. OP mentioned phpMyAdmin.conf but I just searched my entire hard drive for that file and I don't have it even though I have phpMyAdmin installed. `find / -type f -iname "*phpmyadmin.conf*"` returns no files. So I have zero idea what file you're suggesting adding these lines to.

Comment: the path of the .conf file that contains those lines is not universal and depends on the setup. on my centos server there is a separate /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf file. this setting could be set in the main httpd.conf or some other .conf in a subfolder of where the main apache configuration is.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your phpMyAdmin configuration file:

```
vim /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf
```

Then change all "Deny from All" to "Deny from None" and "Allow form None" to "Allow from All".
That should work :)

Comment: PHPMyAdmin must have changed something since all these answers because I have it installed and cannot find this file anywhere on my hard drive. `find / -type f -iname "*phpmyadmin.conf*"` returns absolutely nothing at all. This file is not called that anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and sharing the correct solution here:

To allow connections from All ips in phpMyAdmin directory settings you should change the code like this:

```c
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require all granted   # Add This to skip other requirements
       Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Allow,Deny  # change order to first apply allows, then deny
     Allow from All    # change this from deny to allow from all
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
     Deny from 47.23.165.43  # Bad IPs which should be blocked
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

but if you want to be able to deny some ips and accpet all other ips for apache 2.4 change `# Apache 2.4 <RequireAny>` part as this:

```c
 # Apache 2.4
 <RequireAll> # change requirement to check all parameters
   Require all granted          # Add This to allow all requests
   Require not ip 47.23.165.43  # Bad IPs which should be blocked
   Require not ip 43.80         # Bad IPs which should be blocked
   Require not ip other.bad.ips # Bad IPs which should be blocked
 </RequireAll>
```

Comment: Again, suggesting edits without saying what file those edits go in = useless answer.

Comment: @JohnSmith This is not an static file to edit, its apache's configuration which can be located in various locations/file-names based on OS and user configs and includes.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me under CentOS 7.

Assuming you have installed phpmyadmin with yum.

First, check in the localhost by loading http://localhost/phpmyadmin in your browser.
If you get the forbidden message, probably is because php is not installed.
In my case, I remove phpmyadmin installation, install php and install phpmyadmin again:
(as root)
yum remove phpmyadmin
yum install php
yum install phpmyadmin
service httpd restart

These steps fixed the problem in the local machine.

Now, edit /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf if you want to add permissions for another machine (i.e. 192.168.1.10). By default, it allows access only for localhost.

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require ip ::1
       Require ip 192.168.1.11
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Restart httpd service:
service httpd restart

Answer (score 0):

Did you perform the following as well? This helped me:

```
    mkdir /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/tmp

    chmod 777 /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/tmp

    chown -R apache:apache /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
    
    yum install -y policycoreutils-python-utils
    
    semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/'
    
    semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/tmp(/.*)?'
    
    restorecon -Rv '/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/'
```

Then restart apache service: **systemctl restart httpd**

Answer (score -1):

```
Require local
```

to

```
Require all granted
```

then restart the xampp services.