# "Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource." on phpMyAdmin in Mac Os

Tags: php, mysql, macos, phpmyadmin

I tried to install phpMyadmin in MacOs. But When I go to `localhost/phpmyadmin` it says `Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource.` My phpMyAdmin folder is in
**/usr/local** folder in **Finder**. I configured the `phpmyadmin.conf` file with `sudo nano /etc/apache2/other/phpmyadmin.conf` with the following codes:

```
<Directory /usr/local/phpmyadmin>
        Options Indexes
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        allow from 127.0.0.1
        allow from 192.168.1.0/15
</Directory>
```

What should I do to get rid of this error?

Comment: look at https://support.apple.com/guide/terminal/make-a-file-executable-apdd100908f-06b3-4e63-8a87-32e71241bab4/mac
I think problem on owner of files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find file `httpd-xammp.conf`, change 'Require local' to 'Require all granted', save file and restart apache

Comment: I'm not using xampp. I'm using apache2 and mysql server separatly, installed from homebrew.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23235363/forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-phpmyadmin-on-this-server)

Comment: I tried them. None of the solution works for me.

Comment: Did you restart apache after every change in config file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check 2 things:

- that your phpmyadmin folder (`/usr/local/share/phpmyadmin` by default, but judging by your question I assume it's `/usr/local/phpmyadmin`; be sure to check on that too) is readable by your user and that directories that needs to be writeable by you are.
- that you have correct order for Allow and Deny settings for that directory (you either deny from all and then allow from certain locations, or allow from all locations and then disallow from some).

I suggest changing the config file to look like this:

```html
<Directory /usr/local/phpMyAdmin/>
    Options Indexes
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Allow from 192.168.1.0/15
</Directory>
```

Make sure that the path in `<Directory /usr/local/phpMyAdmin/>` is pointing to your phpmyadmin location.

Also I'm not sure there should be `Options Indexes` line in the config, try removing it temporarily.

Upd: You need to restart apache after making changes to config files (usually it's `sudo service apache2 restart`)